# ngRepeat breaks directive's functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives that are wired together (minimal code samples are provided):

- one is for validation purposes (*apValidation*).

  ```
  module.directive('apValidation', ['$compile', function($compile){
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          compile: function (element) {
          element.removeAttr('ap-validation');   // to avoid infinite compilation
          element.attr('ng-blur', 'testMe()');   // this method has to be called for the validation to happen
          var fn = $compile(element);
              return function (scope) {
                  fn(scope);
                };
          },
          controller: function ($scope, $attrs) {
             $scope.testMe = function () {
                 alert("Validating current text field");
             };
          }
      }
  }]);
  ```
- the other is a reusable text field component, defined as a directive with isolated scope, that makes use of the validation directive (*apTextField*).

  ```
  module.directive('apTextField', function(){
      return{
          restrict: 'E',
          replace:true,
          scope: {
              name: '@',
              label: '@'
          },
      template: '<div>{{label}}: <input type="text" id="someId" name="{{name}}" ap-validation></input></div>'

     }
  });
  ```

The problem I'm facing is that when I'm using my text field directive in a *ngRepeat* context, somehow the validation function, that is triggered by a blur event in this case, is no longer called. 
However, the validation is working just fine outside the ngRepeat context.

```
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="MainController">
<div>
     Without ng-repeat<br>
     <div ng-init="field = {name: 'age', label: 'Age'}">
       <ap-text-field 
                label={{field.label}}
                name="{{field.name}}">
              </ap-text-field>  
     </div><br>

     With ng-repeat<br>

        <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
              <ap-text-field 
                label={{field.label}}
                name="{{field.name}}">
              </ap-text-field>  
        </div>
</div>
```

I know that ngRepeat creates a new isolatedScope, but I fail to understand how this impacts my directive in this case, and what a proper solution to this problem is.

I've prepared a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DanielBot/nymdcL1z/) to best describe my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that the `ngRepeat` directive has already compiled its repeater and has ripped it out of the DOM (to be re-inserted during a $watchCollection() callback); Therefore, the following code `var fn = $compile(element);` compiles an element that was ripped out from the DOM. So, the solution is to compile the new `element` provided to the return callback:

```
compile: function (element) {
      element.removeAttr('ap-validation');   // to avoid infinite compilation
      element.attr('ng-blur', 'testMe()');   // this method has to be called for the validation to happen
      return function (scope, element) {
                            //^ the new element
        $compile(element)(scope);
      };
    }
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/g3yeg5xp/